# Elasticsearch: Make Histogram Return All Possible Buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, I would like to do a date histogram over sime period of time, with some given step size, and then do some aggregations inside the buckets.
With the following query:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
    "query": {
      "range": {
        "created_at": {
          "gte": 1640869094,
          "lte": 1641473894
        }
      }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "fixed_interval": "30m"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "some_value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query tane is about 1 week, and the histogram step is 30 minutes.
I have 3 documents in this index, all created at the same time.

What I get is a histogram with a single time bucket, since all the available documents are in that one time step.
What I *want* is to get back every single time bucket, where the result for the average would be 0 or `null` (since there are no docs in those buckets).
I don't think adding those buckets by hand in the backend is possible since I wouldn't know which buckets exist and which don't - wouldn't know how to fill the gaps.
Is there such a funcionality in Elastic?